# Merging multiple blobs of same file into one to get back original pdf file

Tags: node.js, sql-server, binary, base64, blob

I am retrieving pdf file stored in my database as blob. But some pdf files are stored in multiple columns as blob. Now how to combine these blobs to get back original file

If the file is stored in a single column then my code works fine. But for a file stored in multiple columns having multiple blobs it doesn't work

```
let finalBinary = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        let binary = "";
        // data.data[i].FILE_DATA.data is a buffer array
        let bytes = new Uint8Array(data.data[i].FILE_DATA.data);
        let len = bytes.byteLength;
        for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
          binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[j]);
        }
        finalBinary = finalBinary + binary;
      }
window.open(
        "data:application/pdf;base64," + escape(window.btoa(finalBinary))
      );
```

Actual result comes as failed to load pdf for multiple column pdf. But works fine for single column pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be breaking your binary data in a number of ways. `let finalBinary = "";` and `let binary = "";` are string types for one thing.

Try the following to concatenate byte arrays, e.g.:

```
var btoa = require('btoa'); // npm install btoa

function ConcatUint8Arrays(a, b) {
    const result = new Uint8Array(a.length + b.length);
    result.set(a, 0); //Copy a into result
    result.set(b, a.length); //Copy b into result, after a
    return result;
}

let a = new Uint8Array(5);
a.fill(47);

let b = new Uint8Array(5);
b.fill(74);

let c = ConcatUint8Arrays(a, b);

console.log(c);
console.log(btoa(c));
```

Which gives you the result:

```
Uint8Array [
  47, 47, 47, 47, 47,
  74, 74, 74, 74, 74
]
NDcsNDcsNDcsNDcsNDcsNzQsNzQsNzQsNzQsNzQ=
```

Plumbing that into your original code, e.g.:

```
function ConcatArrays(a, b) {
    const result = new (a.construtor)(a.length + b.length);
    result.set(a, 0); //Copy a into result
    result.set(b, a.length); //Copy b into result, after a
    return result;
}

let finalBinary = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    // data.data[i].FILE_DATA.data is a buffer array
    let bytes = new Uint8Array(data.data[i].FILE_DATA.data);
    finalBinary = ConcatArrays(finalBinary, bytes);
}
window.open(
    "data:application/pdf;base64," + escape(window.btoa(finalBinary))
);
```

Hope this helps.